# Web Client Error: "text/xml" of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8)

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, ws-security

Wrote a Visual Studio 2010 WCF web service written in C#.NET using Framework 4.0.
My web service calls a Java Web Service that uses HTTPS, WS-Security, and Mtom and I need to process the results.
The Java web service does not want the

```
<u:Timestamp><u:Created><u:Expires></u:Timestamp>
```

section in the Header.

Current Issue:
When I test the call to listStuff the response to the web service call shows the data I am looking for (using Fiddler) but I am getting the following error in the WCF Test Client:

"text/xml" of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8).  If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly.

**How can I work around the fact that the web service I am calling is not returning the "charset=utf-8" in their response?**

```
tried <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
tried <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/>
tried <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12"/>
tried <mtomMessageEncoding/>
```

It looks like WS-Security and Mtom are working.

Steps used to create my web service:

Open Visual Studio 2010.

File -> New -> Project.

WCF -> Service Application.
Change Name to MyWebService.
Change Location to C:\MyWebService.
Change Solution Name to MyWebService.
Click OK button.

Displays Service1.svc.cs file.

Right click on the public class name Service1.
Refactor -> Rename.
Change Name: EstuffService.
Click OK button then Apply button.

Open Service1.svc.cs.
Add the following method:

```
    public String listStuff()
    {
        return "Called listStuff()";
    }
```

Open IService1.cs and add the following to public interface IService1.

```
    [OperationContract]
    String listStuff();
```

NOW TEST METHOD.

Select Service1.svc.cs file.
Debug -> Start Debugging.
Opens WCF Test Client window.
Double click on listStuff.
Opens listStuff tab.
Click Invoke button.
Displays Security Warning.
Click OK button.
Response contains “Called listStuff()" in Value field.

WORKS!  NOW TIME TO ADD THE JAVA WEB SERVICE LOGIC.

ADD SERVICE REFERENCE.

Solution Explorer -> Right Click Service Reference -> Add Service Reference.

Enter Address:
    https://the.stuff.com/createFiling?wsdl

Click Go button.

Expand createStuffService.

Click on CreateMTOMInterface.

Enter Namespace:  createStuffService.

Click OK button.

Project -> Create Publish Settings.
Select Application tab.
Target Framework: .NET Framework 4.
Displays Target Framework Change message.
Click Yes button.

Made the following changes to the default code:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Service1.svc.cs
//
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using MyWebService.createStuffService;
using System.IdentityModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace MyWebService
{
    public class EstuffService : IService1
    {
        public String listStuff()
        {
            CreateMTOMInterfaceClient estuffService = getEstuffService();
            try
            {
                stuff[] stuffs = estuffService.listStuff();
                return "listStuff returned " + stuffs.Length.ToString() + " rows.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
            // was - return "Called listStuff()";
        }

        // ADDED the following to use the CustomeCredentials
        public CreateMTOMInterfaceClient getEstuffService()
        {
            CreateMTOMInterfaceClient service = new CreateMTOMInterfaceClient();

            service.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove<ClientCredentials>();
            service.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new CustomCredentials());

            service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "[UserName]";
            service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "[Password]";

            return service;
        }
        // END ADDED
    }

    // ADDED 
    // The following logic comes from 
    // https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/nov/24/wcf-wssecurity-and-wse-nonce-authentication
    // with a couple of changes as noted.  Thanks Rick Strahl.

    public class CustomCredentials : ClientCredentials
    {
        public CustomCredentials()
        { }

        protected CustomCredentials(CustomCredentials cc)
            : base(cc)
        { }

        public override System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenManager CreateSecurityTokenManager()
        {
            return new CustomSecurityTokenManager(this);
        }

        protected override ClientCredentials CloneCore()
        {
            return new CustomCredentials(this);
        }
    }

    public class CustomSecurityTokenManager : ClientCredentialsSecurityTokenManager
    {
        public CustomSecurityTokenManager(CustomCredentials cred)
            : base(cred)
        { }

        public override System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenSerializer CreateSecurityTokenSerializer(System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenVersion version)
        {
            return new CustomTokenSerializer(System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityVersion.WSSecurity11);
        }
    }

    public class CustomTokenSerializer : WSSecurityTokenSerializer
    {
        public CustomTokenSerializer(SecurityVersion sv)
            : base(sv)
        { }

        protected override void WriteTokenCore(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer,
                                                System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken token)
        {
            UserNameSecurityToken userToken = token as UserNameSecurityToken;

            string tokennamespace = "o";

            DateTime created = DateTime.UtcNow;  // was .Now;
            string createdStr = created.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"); // was "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ"

            // unique Nonce value - encode with SHA-1 for 'randomness'
            // in theory the nonce could just be the GUID by itself
            string phrase = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var nonce = GetSHA1String(phrase);

            // in this case password is plain text
            // for digest mode password needs to be encoded as:
            // PasswordAsDigest = Base64(SHA-1(Nonce + Created + Password))
            // and profile needs to change to
            //string password = GetSHA1String(nonce + createdStr + userToken.Password);

            string password = userToken.Password;

            writer.WriteRaw(string.Format(
            "<{0}:UsernameToken u:Id=\"" + token.Id +
            "\" xmlns:u=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\">" +
            "<{0}:Username>" + userToken.UserName + "</{0}:Username>" +
            "<{0}:Password Type=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText\">" +
            password + "</{0}:Password>" +
            "<{0}:Nonce EncodingType=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary\">" +
            nonce + "</{0}:Nonce>" +
            "<u:Created>" + createdStr + "</u:Created></{0}:UsernameToken>", tokennamespace));
        }

        protected string GetSHA1String(string phrase)
        {
            SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1Hasher = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] hashedDataBytes = sha1Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(phrase));
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashedDataBytes);
        }

    }
    // END ADDED 
}
//
// END Service1.svc.cs
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// IService1.cs
//
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace MyWebService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        // ADDED
        [OperationContract]
        String listStuff();
        // END ADDED
    }

}
//
// END IService1.cs
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Web.config
//
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <!--
        The <authentication> section enables configuration 
        of the security authentication mode used by 
        ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <!--
        The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
        of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
        during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
        it enables developers to configure html error pages 
        to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
         <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
         <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
    -->
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
    <!-- ADDED -->
    <!--tried <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>-->
    <!--tried <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/> -->
    <!-- END ADDED -->
  </system.web>
  <!-- 
      The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
      Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
  -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="createStuffServiceSoapBinding">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="createStuffServiceSoapBinding1"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <!-- Added -->
      <!--tried <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12"/>-->
      <!--tried <mtomMessageEncoding/>-->
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="CustomSoapBinding">
          <security includeTimestamp="false" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic256" requireDerivedKeys="false" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"/>
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11"/>
          <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
      <!-- End Added -->
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <!-- Was binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="createStuffServiceSoapBinding"-->
      <endpoint address="https://the.stuff.com/createFiling" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomSoapBinding" contract="createStuffService.CreateMTOMInterface" name="createStuffServicePort"/>
    </client>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyWebService.Service1Behavior" name="MyWebService.EstuffService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyWebService.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <!--tried <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" policyVersion="Policy15"/>-->
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyWebService.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
//
// END Web.config
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

This is my Fiddler results from the call.

```
*** REQUEST Captured using Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger ***
POST https://the.stuff.com/services/createFiling HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Host: the.stuff.com
Content-Length: 1279
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope 
xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
<VsDebuggerCausalityData 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">
uIDPo8CYUJmfemFDgV85fb9Z8dwBAAAAHYQCoVVch0SXHY5oNUdGeXF1Nv5vBlNMnDbXQEH7yAoACQAA
</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
<o:Security 
s:mustUnderstand="1" 
xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<o:UsernameToken 
u:Id="uuid-920edd97-b092-4f62-a2f2-0463dd064628-10" 
xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<o:Username>
[UserName]
</o:Username>
<o:Password 
Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">
[Password]
</o:Password>
<o:Nonce 
EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">
SsN9bPcfZEsAulkbEtN2FksKXWg=
</o:Nonce>
<u:Created>2016-10-12T16:44:30.147Z</u:Created>
</o:UsernameToken>
</o:Security>
</s:Header>
<s:Body 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<listStuff xmlns="http://efile.the.stuff.com/"/>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
*** END REQUEST Captured using Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger ***

*** RESPONSE Captured using Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger ***
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
XM: ttc1a
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; 
boundary="uuid:89bea26c-8f7d-4dcf-8809-c5cb9697a1f0"; start="<root.message@cxf.apache.org>"; start-info="text/xml"
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 16:44:32 GMT
Set-Cookie: F5-SESSION-PERSIST=889397770.63520.0000; path=/
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 53173

--uuid:89bea26c-8f7d-4dcf-8809-c5cb9697a1f0
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body><ns2:listStuffResponse xmlns:ns2="http://efile.the.stuff.com/">
<stuff><id>1</id><name>Stuff1</name><abbreviation>A001</abbreviation></stuff>
... left out stuff 2 to 536 ...
<stuff><id>537</id><name>Stuff537</name><abbreviation>A537</abbreviation></stuff>
</ns2:listStuffResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
--uuid:89bea26c-8f7d-4dcf-8809-c5cb9697a1f0--
*** END RESPONSE Captured using Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger ***
```

This is my XML results from the WCF Test Client.

```
*** REQUEST Captured from WCF Test Client ***
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" 
xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<s:Header>
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IService1/listStuff</a:Action>
<a:MessageID>urn:uuid:8a03d3ad-dd79-4745-b9bb-a55ce293d314</a:MessageID>
<a:ReplyTo>
<a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
</a:ReplyTo>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
<listStuff xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
*** END REQUEST Captured from WCF Test Client ***

*** RESPONSE Captured from WCF Test Client ***
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" 
xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" 
u:Id="_2">http://tempuri.org/IService1/listStuffResponse</a:Action>
<a:RelatesTo u:Id="_3">urn:uuid:26883546-39ea-44e0-83b2-d3cee32ba8b0</a:RelatesTo>
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" 
xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-303895ea-d557-4df1-a665-2f94391dd40d-15">
<u:Created>2016-10-12T16:44:32.350Z</u:Created>
<u:Expires>2016-10-12T16:49:32.350Z</u:Expires>
</u:Timestamp>
<c:DerivedKeyToken u:Id="uuid-303895ea-d557-4df1-a665-2f94391dd40d-13" 
xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">
<o:SecurityTokenReference>
<o:Reference URI="urn:uuid:6e0ba079-fc3c-4ae9-9186-e0e3f928a113" 
ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct" />
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
<c:Offset>0</c:Offset>
<c:Length>24</c:Length>
<c:Nonce>UvseoObRVJeMp2Dv3t/5tg==</c:Nonce>
</c:DerivedKeyToken>
<c:DerivedKeyToken 
u:Id="uuid-303895ea-d557-4df1-a665-2f94391dd40d-14" 
xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">
<o:SecurityTokenReference>
<o:Reference 
URI="urn:uuid:6e0ba079-fc3c-4ae9-9186-e0e3f928a113" 
ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct" />
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
<c:Nonce>gFfWI8QjzYJH8kh/9dzDgA==</c:Nonce>
</c:DerivedKeyToken>
<e:ReferenceList xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<e:DataReference URI="#_1" />
<e:DataReference URI="#_4" />
</e:ReferenceList>
<e:EncryptedData Id="_4" 
Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" 
xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<e:EncryptionMethod 
Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<o:SecurityTokenReference>
<o:Reference 
ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/dk" 
URI="#uuid-303895ea-d557-4df1-a665-2f94391dd40d-14" />
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
<e:CipherData>
<e:CipherValue>... left out the CipherValue ...</e:CipherValue>
</e:CipherData>
</e:EncryptedData>
</o:Security>
</s:Header>
<s:Body u:Id="_0">
<listStuffResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<listStuffResult>
The content type multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; 
boundary="uuid:89bea26c-8f7d-4dcf-8809-c5cb9697a1f0"; start="&lt;root.message@cxf.apache.org&gt;"; 
start-info="text/xml" of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). 
If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes 
of the response were: '--uuid:89bea26c-8f7d-4dcf-8809-c5cb9697a1f0
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: &lt;root.message@cxf.apache.org&gt;

&lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"&gt;
&lt;soap:Body&gt;
&lt;ns2:listStuffResponse 
xmlns:ns2="http://efile.the.stuff.com/"&gt;
&lt;stuff&gt;&lt;id&gt;1&lt;/id&gt;&lt;name&gt;Stuff001&lt;/name&gt;&lt;abbreviation&gt;X001&lt;/abbreviation&gt;&lt;/stuff&gt;
... left out stuff 2 to 6 ...
&lt;stuff&gt;&lt;id&gt;7&lt;/id&gt;&lt;name&gt;Stuff007&lt;/name&gt;&lt;abbreviation&gt;X007&lt;/abbreviation&gt;&lt;'.
</listStuffResult>
</listStuffResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
*** END RESPONSE Captured from WCF Test Client ***
```

Comment: I also have tired <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" policyVersion="Policy15"/>